# Thruk - templating - Add href when host is member of hostgroup

Tags: thruk

In the **_block.tt** its possible to add href when **custom_vars_host** is present.

```
[% IF custom_vars_host.size > 0 %]
[% FOREACH cust = custom_vars_host %]
[% IF cust.key == "ilo" || cust.key == "drac") %]
<td><a href='https://[% cust.value %]/'>...</a></td>
[% END %]
[% END %]
[% END %]
```

Is there a way to add link when **host is member of a hostgroup**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way as the macro

> [% IF host.groups.size > 0 %]
>
> [% FOREACH group IN host.groups.sort %]
>
> [% IF group == "metrics-win" %]
>
> [% END %]
>
> [% END %]
>
> [% END %]

Answer (score 0):

extending the `_block.tt` template could lead to maintainance issues because you have to double check your changes after each update. You could use the new rest api together with the js action menus like in this example: https://thruk.org/documentation/action-menu.html#sending-commands